# python selenium interact with input of type search

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, find, element

this is a search page.  and its structure looks like this.

```
<input type="search" title="Search Site" aria-label="Keywords" placeholder="Keywords" autocomplete="off" value="">

<div class="header2020-search-button">
    <button class="fast fat-search">
        <span class="hid-text">Search</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Am trying to interact with this text box using selenium and search for a word Collapse.  my code looks like this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search Site')]").send_keys("Collapse")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="fast fat-search"]').click()
```

the send keys does not work.  results an error.

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid
> selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
> //input[@title='Search Site')] because of the following error:
> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
> '//input[@title='Search Site')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo.
In the HTML the element class names are "fas fa-search" while in code I see "fast fat-search"
I would suggest you using the following for that:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="header2020-search-button"]//button[contains(@class,"search")]').click()
```

Comment: fixed ... the typo ... but thats not the error.

Answer (score 0):

ok i got the error ....  some times a different layout helps to see better.

there was an extra ) in the xpath.

Comment: I see, your typo is in `//input[@title='Search Site')]` XPath. While my suggested solution anyway should work :)

Comment: I believe it's better to delete this question rather than answering your own solution which is actually a very basic thing which is again a syntax error